# How to implement aside tag where it isn't compatible?

Tags: php, html, css, cross-browser

When i open my website in safari browser version below 4.1 then aside tag dosen't work but i have to make it work somehow. I needed expert solution on this. Please Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: *Xorifelse grabs his magic 8 ball* Your question is hazy, [please try again](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: http://www.logiticks.com/web/a-knockout-solution-to-checkbox-selection-in-a-multi-layer-dynamic-row/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this in style in the head:

`<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

Actually browsers if do not understand a tag it take it as a inline element. So to make any new html5 tag backwards compatible all you have to do is make it's display as block.

```
aside { display: block;}
```